# Prove that the sequence of sets is nondecreasing, and find its limit

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the sequence of sets, $\{C_k\}$, is nondecreasing, and find $\lim_{x \to \infty} \{C_k\}$, where $C_k = \{x : \frac{1}{k} \leq x \leq 3-\frac{1}{k}\}$, $k = 1, 2, 3, ...$

Here is my attempt at both parts of the problem:

To show that $\{C_k\}$ is nondecreasing, let $C_k = \{x : \frac{1}{k} \leq x \leq 3-\frac{1}{k}\}$ and $C_{k+1} = \{x : \frac{1}{k+1} \leq x \leq 3-\frac{1}{k+1}\}$. Now note that, for any $x \in C_{k}$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{k+1} < \frac{1}{k} \leq x \leq 3-\frac{1}{k} < 3 - \frac{1}{k+1}
\end{align}

so that our chosen $x$ is also an element of $C_{k+1}$. Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, we have $C_k \subset C_{k+1}$, as desired.

Next, since $\{C_k\}$ is nondecreasing, we know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \{C_k\} = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{C_k\}$. Plugging in some values for $k$,
\begin{align}
C_1 = \{x : 1 \leq x \leq 2\}\\
C_2 = \{x : \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{5}{2}\}\\
\vdots\\
\lim_{x \to \infty} \{C_k\} = \{x : 0 < x < 3\}
\end{align}

My main question about the second part is: should the interval be open or closed? I think that since lower bound is getting "close" to $0$, and the upper bound is getting "close" to $3$, it makes sense to have an open interval, as this represents all values infinitely close to the endpoints, exclusive. Would it be correct to say that a closed interval would be "too big", i.e., more than the union of the sets?

I hope my question, and notation, are clear. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would it be correct to say that a closed interval would be "too big", i.e., more than the union of the sets?

Yes.  More precisely, if we assumed (towards a contradiction) that $0 \in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k,$ then this would require the existence of some positive integer $k$ such that $$\frac{1}{k} \leq 0 \leq 3-\frac{1}{k} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 1 \leq 0\cdot k = 0.$$ Since no such positive integer exists, $0\not\in \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k.$

We can similarly show that $3$ is not in any of the sets in the sequence, so it is not in the union.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is the open interval $(0,3)$. When you have a nondecreasing sequence of sets, its limit is its union. In this case, that union is $(0,3)$.